# Upgrade Angular v14.20 to v15.0

Tags: angular

am i obligated to update the Angular Material when i upgrade Angular version?

Example: I am updating Angular v14.20 to Angular v15.0, in the steps, they includes update Angular Material, but am i obligated to do this?

Thanks all.

Update Angular 14.20 to 15.0 whithout update Angular Material

Comment: You definitely should update Material as well. If new material components are the problem you can still use the ["legacy" components](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/guides/v15-mdc-migration.md#what-has-changed).

Comment: There is helpful page https://update.angular.io/

Comment: why you don't want to update angular material ?

Comment: @Indraraj26 cuz some components had changes, and i dont want these changes in my project